# How do I convert my HBase cluster to use Google Cloud Bigtable?

Tags: hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm currently running a HBase Cluster on Google Cloud Platform and would like to switch it to using Cloud Bigtable -- what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Create a Cloud Bigtable cluster](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/creating-cluster)
2. [Test that it works](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-shell-quickstart) by running the Quickstart.
3. Start up a [HBase Export](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#export) MapReduce
4. We recommend you store the parts on [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview).
5. [Setup a HBase 1.0.x environment](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/creating-hadoop-cluster) and put the `hbase-site.xml` file that you created as part of the Quickstart into your `hbase/conf` folder.  (You may need to modify this for your cluster)
6. See the [HBase Bulk Import documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.bulk.load)
7. When that completes, you can verify your data using the images you created for your Quickstart (above).

You'll note that you can now access Cloud Bigtable using the [HBase 1.0 APIs](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/index.html).  You can find additional [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/) and [examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples). We will be posting more over the coming days and weeks as well as expanding on this answer.